# "I will be back into the office at 3pm." or "I will be back in the office at 3pm"?

Tags: word-choice

I have another questions which are:

> "I will be back into the office at 3pm."

or

> "I will be back in the office at 3pm"?

and

> "As you can read on my report"

or

> "As you can read at my report"?

Comment: People generally use "in," but it wouldn't be weird to hear someone use "into."

Comment: "Back into" would be odd.  It means to park a car front end facing out or to bump into something while moving backwards.  English seems almost impossible to me.  I'm sure I couldn't speak it if I hadn't learned as a child.

Comment: "into the office" sounds like you're going into a physical office. "The office" is typically used as a synonym for "my workplace".

Comment: I think that I already understood the difference between them. Many thanks!

Comment: Regarding my second question, can you clarify me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**The correct usage is 'back in the office'.**

'Into' is used to denote movement. 'In' is used to denote position. So "I am going into the office", but "I am in the office". Therefore if you are describing where you will be at 3pm you use 'in'.

You can say "I will come back into the office before 3pm", because that describes a movement that will happen before 3pm. Informally 'I will come back in the office' is also used, but not the other way.

If you are a hippie escaped from the sixties you can also be "really into this music", but that's something completely different.